# Null boolean props if not given in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In a Vue component, I have this:

```
props: {
    foo: Boolean
}, 
mounted() {
    console.log(this.foo) 
}
```

If I call my component without `foo`:

```
<component/>
```

I read `false` on the console. I would like to get `null` if the property is not given and the boolean value elsewhere.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add default value :

```
props: {
    foo: {
      type:Boolean,
       default: null
    }
},
```